# Worst Performance during Record Insertion in table - SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT COL1,COL2,COL3......COL50 
INTO newtable
FROM TABLEX AS t1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLEY t2 ON t1.col1 = t2.col1
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLEZ t3 ON t1.col5 = t3.col5
```

More than 3 hours and still executing while inserting records to table, record count is 118 million.

Any suggestions to improve performance? Please.

Comment: @juergen: No Index on the table

Comment: How long does the `select` take without inserting?

Comment: If its not much of an importance, you can change [Recovery Model to Simple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/recovery-models-sql-server). Moreover if by any chance you are using `.Net` Language to execute this query, simply use `SqlBulkCopy`

Comment: Please show table structures & indexes

Comment: @juergend: 2hr 35 min

Comment: Then that is the problem. How did you survive that long without adding indexes to your tables? You really need to add them. Read a tutorial about it.

Comment: @juergend: i had column store index on my key columnn, doesn't improve much any suggestion ?

Comment: Why did you think adding a columnstore index on a single column would help?